# C++ initializer/constructor for basic types

Tags: c++

Given the following code, to what does junk1 point at the end of the function before return?

```
static void junkf(void)
{
   static const char s_char = char();
   const char *junk1 = &s_char;
   static const int s_int = int();
   const int *junk2 = &s_int;
}
```

(Note that this is my unrolling of a function from a template class that substitutes "char" or "int" according to the  declaration.  I assume that junk2 points to an int with a zero value -- correct?)

What is the "char()" or "int()" construct called in the C++ language?  I want to learn more about this construct for basic types, but can't seem to find anything about it.  Is this an initializer, or a constructor, or ...?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the function, `junk1` points to the exact same thing you told it to point to — `s_char`.

Since `junk1` dies at the end of the function, whether `s_car` lives beyond that is not part of any useful discussion.

---

Rewriting the question slightly based on comments:

```
const char c = char();  // what value does `c` have, and why?
const char* ptr = &c;   // what does `ptr` point to?
```

`char()` is an expression containing the construction of an anonymous, temporary `char`. Instantiating a type with an empty constructor argument list performs value-initialisation (§8.5/10)<sup>†</sup>. §8.5/7 tell us that, during value-initialisation, since `char` is not a class or array type, it will be zero-initialised.

Our `c` is initialised from this temporary, so it takes on the value `0`. This effectively results in `ptr` being a zero-length, null-terminated C string.

<sup><sup>†</sup> A declaration like `char c;` does *not* satisfy this criterion!</sup>

Comment: My first question was perhaps better phrased as asking what is in s_char after initialization.  I assume the value initialization char() is a NUL (0) byte, so junk1 in practice points to an empty string.  My second question was the more important, and thanks to @pepper_chico for answering that!

Comment: @MarkLudwig: So really the question should be `const char c = char(); const char* ptr = &c; // what does ptr point to?`?

Comment: Right, for this question, the character does not need to be static.  My example was taken from some code I found (where the variable is and needs to be static for contexual reasons).  I'm trying to add C++ to my list of fluent languages, and it's the value-initialization form for the basic types that I am trying to focus on here: what value is stored in c?  The pointer is only interesting, because it is passed into functions that assume it points to a NUL-terminated string.  What is the value supplied by all of the value-initialization forms for all of the data types?  Thinking they supply 0s.

Comment: @MarkLudwig: The short answer is that the code in my comment above indeed results in `ptr` being a zero-length, null-terminated C string.